# Firestore Query load all in language

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database and an Android app that needs to load in articles in the language of the device. So I've made this structure (see screenshot below). But when the article is not available in the language (not every article has every translation), the default (English) needs to be loaded.

How would I query this?

[image: FireStore structure]

Answer (score 0):

Since Firestore doesn't support OR conditions in queries, this will have to be a two-step process:

1. Try to load the device-language version of the article.
2. If that gives no result, load the English language version of the article.

Comment: the problem is I want to load in all articles without the Id's known beforehand. So I need to do something like db.collection("articles") and then foreach article load in the english (for example) article

Comment: It sounds like your data structure is not ideal for that type of query. In NoSQL you often have to adapt/augment your data model for the use-cases of your app. Imagine how you'd like it to work from your code, and then modify your data model to fit that.